# Trouble copying several image files with the same name into existing folder

Tags: python

I have a directory ("E:images") consisting of several hundred folders. Each folder contains about five separate image files. I would like to take a specific image file from each folder and place them in a separate folder called "test". The image in each folder starts with "state_0". I feel like I should be able to copy each file by that string but I'm not even able to transfer any images by file type at the moment.

This seems like it should be pretty straight forward but I'm not getting any errors and nothing is being copied into my folder when I run the script.

This is what I have:

```
import os
import shutil
import glob


files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(r'E:\\images', "*.bmp"))
for file in files:
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        shutil.copy2(file, r'E:\\test')
```

Comment: Do the images you want to transfer start with "state_0" and is that unique to the files you want to transfer?

Comment: I don't understand why you're putting double-backslashes in a string that's already raw; if it's raw then you don't have to escape backslashes.

Comment: Did the answer below work for you? If so, please upvote/accept the answer so others know it is correct. Thanks.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman That is correct. Each image file starts with "state_0". It is unique to the file I want to transfer. The other 4 images in each folder are "state_1","state_2", etc.

Comment: Then the solution below will work for you.

Comment: @RandomDavis I didn't notice I did that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import glob
import shutil

files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(r'E:\images', '*.bmp'))

for file in files:
    print(file)
    # if file is a bmp and has state_0 in filename
    if file.endswith('bmp') and 'state_0' in file:
        print(file)
        # copy file into test 
        shutil.copy2(file, r'E:\test')
```

Comment: I just tested it out and the "test" folder is still empty.

Comment: it works for me. I am on *nix not windows, so my guess is your file path is incorrect? try adding a print(file) above '# copy file into test' and see if it is finding your files.

Comment: Try the code above with the print statements.

Comment: Hmm. No luck with print(file) either. I'm not seeing where/how the file path is incorrect. I am running the script through spyder (python3.9) on a USB drive. Both folders I'm trying to work with are also on the USB drive (E:).

Comment: Try a print(files) after the files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(r'E:\images', '*.bmp')). If that doesn't print anything, the script can't see your files.

Comment: That time I got the response "<generator object _iglob at 0x000001E2863BFC10>" in the console. So I'm guessing it's not seeing the files?

Comment: ok. Try glob.glob rather than glob.iglob.

Comment: That time the response to print(files) after files = glob.iglob(os.path.join(r'E:\images', '*.bmp')) was "[]" in the console. Northing for print(file) nor in the test folder.

Comment: You are certain there are files in E:\images that end with '.bmp'? I'm not familiar with Spyder but my guess is there is something specific to that environment.

Comment: Yeah. I am certain those files are there. I have WinPython and Spyder running off my USB so I can log onto different workstation at work and take everything with me. I'm not devoted to Spyder if you have a better suggestion.

Comment: It works without issue on my system. For our sanity, can you move the files into a folder called images that is located in the same drive and directory as your script? If that works we'll eliminate path issues.